# Error with duplicated rownames in R, but anyduplicated(rownames()) returns nothing?

Tags: r, duplicates

I'm running the candidate.overlap function in the pSI package, and getting an error message about row names:

```
    > candidate.overlap(pSIs = psI_output, candidate.genes = dat2.1)
Error in `row.names<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, value = value) : 
   duplicate 'row.names' are not allowed
In addition: Warning message:
non-unique values when setting 'row.names': ‘C21ORF59’, ‘C6ORF165’
```

The sample filter run with the same candidate.genes list doesn't throw an error message, so I know the function and dat2.1 are not the error.

```
 > candidate.overlap(pSIs = sample.data$pSI.output, candidate.genes = dat2.1)
    $pSi_0.0001
    [1] Amygdala.Young.Adulthood_0.0001    Cerebellum.Young.Adulthood_0.0001 
    [3] Cortex.Young.Adulthood_0.0001      Hippocampus.Young.Adulthood_0.0001
    [5] Striatum.Young.Adulthood_0.0001    Thalamus.Young.Adulthood_0.0001   
    <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)
```

Reading through answers, I used the make.names function with unique = TRUE because I was running into problems with row names previously, but thought I had solved it before this step. I checked for duplicated rownames:

```
> anyDuplicated(rownames(psI_output))
[1] 0
> anyDuplicated(rownames(sample.data$pSI.output))
[1] 0
```

And checked str: (there are values in the data frame, they are not all NA)

```
> str(psI_output)
'data.frame':   55993 obs. of  12 variables:
 $ Adipose...Subcutaneous             : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Artery...Tibial                    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Artery...Aorta                     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Artery...Coronary                  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Colon...Transverse                 : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Lung                               : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Stomach                            : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Skin...Sun.Exposed..Lower.leg.     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Skin...Not.Sun.Exposed..Suprapubic.: num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Nerve...Tibial                     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Muscle...Skeletal                  : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Whole.Blood                        : num  NA NA NA NA NA ...
```

Is R having problems with the header, for example skin is repeated twice followed by ...? Or is there a way to detect where the error is occurring?
Any help appreciated.
scien

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Alan Wells from the TSEA/pSI team:

> So the first step we perform in the pSI.list and candidate.overlap functions is to convert all the gene/transcript names to uppercase letters. This is because when we are trying to match these gene names to a user supplied list, we didn’t want to run into issues non-matching due to the case of letters used in the gene name. After converting all of your gene names to uppercase it looks like there are two gene names that are duplicated in your data set, C6ORF165 and C21ORF59.

It's interesting that make.names function set to unique = TRUE incorporates the case of the letters into calling a row name unique. Learned something.